# Is there a way to identify if a column is not been used in a SQL Server Database?

Tags: sql-server

I have a big database and a lot tables and I would like to identify what columns are not been called by any store procedure or any query, or not in use.

Comment: this might help you: https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2012/07/19/sql-server-find-column-used-in-stored-procedure-search-stored-procedure-for-column-name-part-2/

Comment: Do you have the database objects in text files in source control? And all the source files for software that connects to your database? If so then `grep` or the windows grep-like `findstr`.

Comment: 1. Install [SSDT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt). 2. Import your database into a database project. 3. Navigate to the column in the table definition, right-click, and choose "Find all references". 4. Celebrate the wonderful times we live in. Now, this is not a full answer as it's not exactly comfortable to do this for all columns. I'm not sure if this could be solved using the [DacFx model](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ssdt/2013/12/23/dacfx-public-model-tutorial/).

Comment: This sound helpful, the problem is there is a lot of ssis packages that can be calling any table or column.

Comment: Shannon I don’t have the scripts.

Comment: @Juan: then you are, in a word, boned. There is no way for SQL Server to know what external applications *potentially* access, and it does not track every such access, because that would be mad inefficient. You can *at best* find completely unused tables, by checking `sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats`, but individual columns are a no-go. You can hook up a profiler, track all incoming queries, and at least in theory find unused columns from there, but only in theory -- I'm not aware of any existing solution that will parse those queries for you and figure out what's used and what's not.

Comment: At this point, you should question why you need this knowledge. Nobody ever got fired for not removing unused columns.

Comment: @JeroenMostert thanks for your wisdom :) I think the best option is to look at the execution plans cache, but this will require to continuously move to another location and have a 30 days of cache and try to evaluate from there. But maybe this is a long shot as you mention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After an investigation I have found a new feature of SQL Server called Query Store where you can find in disk the executions with other information. If you have a SQL Server 2016 instance you can find it in the properties of the data base. There you can change the amount of days to capture and then you can in theory try to find the columns in question. The idea of this technology is to give you more options for performance tuning.

You can find the information with this query :

```
 SELECT TOP 10 qt.query_sql_text, q.query_id, 
    qt.query_text_id, p.plan_id, rs.last_execution_time
FROM sys.query_store_query_text AS qt 
JOIN sys.query_store_query AS q 
    ON qt.query_text_id = q.query_text_id 
JOIN sys.query_store_plan AS p 
    ON q.query_id = p.query_id 
JOIN sys.query_store_runtime_stats AS rs 
    ON p.plan_id = rs.plan_id
    where qt.query_sql_text LIKE '%ColumnToFind%'
ORDER BY rs.last_execution_time;
```

Credits: [Query Store](https://www.sqlshack.com/the-sql-server-query-store-in-action/)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for, but in your DB under views there's a folder for System Views - three of which are the following. Looking in all_objects look for the table name, then use the object_id of that table to select from the other queries. There may be other meta-data here that is appropriate for your need.

```
    SELECT *
    FROM sys.all_objects

    SELECT * 
    FROM sys.all_columns
    WHERE object_id = 981578535

    SELECT *
    FROM sys.all_views
    WHERE object_id = 981578535
```